# Java SQLite database, insert entry giving nullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, methods

I am trying to create a generic method that can add an entry into a SQLite database, using Eclipse and Java.

When the table name is hardcoded it works fine, but when I try to pass in the table name as a string it is giving me a nullPointerException.

below is the method that creates that table:

```
public static void Table()
      {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

          stmt = c.createStatement();
          String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COMPANY " +
                       "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," +
                       " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL, " + 
                       " AGE            INT     NOT NULL, " + 
                       " ADDRESS        TEXT, " + 
                       " SALARY         REAL)"; 
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
          stmt.close();
          c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Table created successfully");
      }
```

and here is the method that inserts an entry into the created table. I want to pass in the table name through the method rather than hard coding it:

```
 public static void Insert(String table, int id, String name, int age, String address, String salary)
      {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
          c.setAutoCommit(false);
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

          String query="INSERT INTO "+table+" (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

          PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(query);

            pstmt.setInt(1,id);
            pstmt.setString(2,name);
            pstmt.setInt(3, age);
            pstmt.setString(4, address);
            pstmt.setString(5, salary);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            pstmt.close();
          c.commit();
          c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Records created successfully");
      }
```

Comment: try to print the "query". and check that the value of the "table" is coming or not.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Table and column names aren't bound by PreparedStatement.  The columns are fixed in your SQL; hard code the table name, too.  You aren't closing your resources properly.  Your error handling isn't right, either.  You don't follow Java coding standards.

Comment: @duffymo what is incorrect about the error handling?

Comment: Printing the complete stack trace is always more info than a single message.  Hardwiring to write to System.err precludes logging to log4j.  System.exit?  The INSERT failure need not be fatal.  You don't rollback the transaction in the catch block - why bother with auto commit false?  You should close your resources in a finally block in individual try/catch.  You shouldn't connect in the method.  Pass the connection in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have small mistake 
just you have created two different PreparedStatement object
So change

```
PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
```

to

```
pstmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
```